# What is missing in the derivation of the moment of inertia of sphere?

Tags: definite-integrals, physics

When we are to calculate the moment of inertial of an object, we basically sum all the infinitesimal moments of inertial of all small elements, so since $m_i /V_i = \sigma$ where $\sigma$ is the density of that small element, which will be constant for the time being.Therefore

$$dm r^2 = \sigma dVr^2$$.For an sphere, $dV = r^2 sin(\phi) dr d\phi d\theta$, and hence

$$I = \frac{\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^R \sigma r^4 sin(\phi) dr d\phi d\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^R r^2 sin(\phi) dr d\phi d\theta}$$

But after calculation these integrals, I get

$$I = \frac{3MR^2}{5}$$.

I check many times that there is no problem in the calculation, but I can not find the problem in the construction since every source that I looked says that

$$I = \frac{2MR^2}{5}$$.

Comment: Solid sphere or hollow sphere?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat As you can see from the limits of the integral, it is a solid sphere.

Comment: With this calculation you are solving the moment of inertia of the sphere with respect to its centre, not with respect to an axis. Since your distance $r$ in $dm\,r^2$ is measured with respect to the centre. Instead you have to write this differential as $dm(r\sin{\phi})^2$

Comment: @HBR That is what I needed, thanks.

Comment: your are welcome @Leth!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find the moment of inertia of a solid sphere with respect to the $z$-axis you should integrate:
$$I = \iiint_B (x^2+y^2) (\sigma dV)=M\frac{\iiint_B (x^2+y^2)  dV}{\iiint_B dV}\\
=M\frac{\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^R (r \sin(\phi))^2\cdot r^2\sin(\phi) dr d\phi d\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^R  r^2 \sin(\phi) dr d\phi d\theta}=\frac{2MR^2}{5}.$$

Comment: I could understand if you state what $z$ is  and why we used $z^2$ ?

Comment: But for a sphere, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$, so instead of  $x^2 + y^2 $, shouldn't we use $R^2 - z^2$ ?

Comment: by the way, it should be $\cos(\phi) $ not $sin(\phi)$

Comment: You have to integrate the square distance from the $z$-axis which is $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Ok, I understood.